# createAction does not insert data in database PHP with jtable

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-jtable

I am using jtable to help users to manage a contact form, However I am having trouble getting it to insert the data into the mysql table with CreateAction.php
the front page code is the folowing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
                    title: 'Contact list',
                    actions: {
                        listAction: '/Pipit/assets/php/list.php',
                        createAction: '/Pipit/assets/php/createAction.php',
                        updateAction: '/Pipit/assets/php/edit.php',
                        deleteAction: '/Pipit/assets/php/delete.php'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        personID: {
                            key: true,
                            list: false
                        },
                        name: {
                            title: 'name',
                        },
                        group: {
                            title: 'group',
                        },
                        phone: {
                            title: 'number',
                        }
                    }
                });
```

THe createAction.php file is the following:

```
    //Insert record into database
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pipit_contacts (name, group, phone) VALUES('" . $_POST["name"] . "', '" . $_POST["group"] . "', ".$_POST['phone']."");

//Get last inserted record (to return to jTable)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pipit_contacts ORDER BY  personID DESC ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//Return result to jTable
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Record'] = $row;
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

Comment: 1. Stop using mysql_*. It's deprecated. 2. Use `or die(mysql_error())` to get an error message. 3. Post said error message.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error
"', ".$_POST['phone'].""); => I should be "','".$_POST['phone']."'");// if it is int, then It is okay

you might need to use mysql_escape_string() to remove any special char there.